# AndEngine License - what should I write in About?

Tags: licensing, andengine, lgpl

I'm using AndEngine in my Android app. I found that this library is distributed under GNU Lesser GPL. 
What should I write in my about view to conform this license?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org already provides that information. Here's the [link](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html) for that. In this link you may find a brief explanation of how to place a program under several licenses including GNU Lesser GPL.

---

**EDIT:** I checked some examples of LGPL'ed software in Ubuntu and their about boxes.

- LibreOffice just prints some copyright information in the about box. Nevertheless, they have an option just to show the license information (also available [online](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/license/)), where it shows the following:

> **Licensing and Legal information**
>
> This product is made available subject
> to the terms of GNU Lesser General Public License Version 3. A copy of
> the LGPL license can be found below.
>
> Jump to LGPL Version 3

- Wine has the following information in its about box (also [online](http://www.winehq.org/license)):

> Wine is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
> the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the
> Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at
> your option) any later version.

Comment: As a comment, I was about to transcribe the text to the main content of the post just to be self-contained. However it is still a considerable amount of text to copy. Therefore I've just provided the link.

Comment: Thank you. I went through this site but I didn't find a guidelines what should I write in 'About'? Can I  write: "AndEngine LGPL" and give a link to both AndEngine site and LGPL text?

Comment: Moreover, being AndEngine LGPL, that doesn't force you to license your software under the LGPL. Even the author published that in his [blog](http://www.andengine.org/blog/2010/11/andengine-and-the-lgpl-clarification/). I would just make a statement saying that your software uses AndEngine which is licensed under LGPL and your name/company in the copyright notice.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is link (ie to a web page) to the LGPL libraries you use to make it easy for your customers to access its source code if they wish. This seems to be the top priority for the FSF (the end user having the right to see the source). Other than that, it is my understanding that linking your code with this LGPL-licensed library is completely okay for a closed-source program, which is why they are discouraging the use of LGPL for new libraries now.